# /usr/bin/env: python2: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to configure Python for my Emacs on Ubuntu, and I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: python2: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me with it? What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as 'off topic' since the question is about setting up the Python programming environment on Ubuntu and usually the first line of Python code on a UNIX system.  Here's an explanation of what this line does and how to configure it for your system :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

Comment: By me the real display is `/usr/bin/env: « python2\r »: No such file or directory`. `/usr/bin/python2` is present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably that's just true. The link `/usr/bin/python2 -> (the real one)` should be provided by your Python package, but that's obviously not the case, nor on any other location where it can be found via the `$PATH`.

You should put the said link in your path at the (an) appropriate place.

Comment: But I have python in path, when I type "python" in my command line, it does open up the terminal. So how do I include in the past as recommended by you?

Comment: That is strange. Normally, `env` should check the path. It also depends on under which circumstances the error occurs: do you have a different `$PATH` than normally? What says `which python2` in the shell?

Comment: on 'which python2', I dont get any anything in the shell. How should I define it ?

Comment: oh, stop. You type `python`, you said, not `python2`. Either change the script to call `python`instead of `python2`, or do a `ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python2`. It is an ugly trick, however, and really should be done by the packet. But I cannot tell you why this isn't the case...

Comment: thanks and appreciate your help

Answer (score 14):

Try this command in terminal

> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python2

or

> sudo apt-get install python2

Comment: I wish to go the symbolic link route as I did in the past, the machine recently had a clean reinstall to El Capitan.  Even as sudo as follows `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2` I get the following 'ln: /usr/bin/python2: Operation not permitted'

Comment: Problem solved.  Using `ln -sf`allowed it to work.  I'd checked it was't already linked using `ls -la | more` so its a bit of a mystery why `-f` worked even after doing a `man ln` and reading about it.  Anyway problem solved.

Comment: FWIW, this works on my version of El Capitan: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04.

To find out what package owns the file:

```
$ apt-file -F find /usr/bin/python2
python-minimal: /usr/bin/python2
```

To find out what packages depend on the package:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends python-minimal
python-minimal
Reverse Depends:
  python2.7-minimal
 |livecd-rootfs
  python-minimal:i386
  python-support
  python2.7-minimal
  python
 |livecd-rootfs
```

It show that if you have `python` package then you should have `python-minimal` package then you should have `/usr/bin/python2` file.

Check whether `/usr/bin` is in `$PATH` inside emacs. If it is and you can't run `/usr/bin/python2` from a shell then you could reinstall `python-minimal` to restore `/usr/bin/python2` file:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-minimal
```