# PySpark Will not start - ‘python’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to setup pyspark on my desktop and interact with it via the terminal. 
I'm following this guide,

http://jmedium.com/pyspark-in-python/

When I run 'pyspark' in the terminal is says,

```
/home/jacob/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark: line 45: python:
command not found
env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

I've followed several guides which all lead to this same issue (some have different details on setting up the .profile. Thus far none have worked correctly).
I have java, python3.6, and Scala installed.
My .profile is configured as follows:

```
#Spark and PySpark Setup
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export SPARK_HOME='/home/jacob/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7'
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
#export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
#export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6.5
```

Note that jupyter notebook is commented out because I want to launch pyspark in the shell right now with out the notebook starting

Interestingly spark-shell launches just fine

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and
Spark 2.1

See Images

I've tried every guide I can find, and since this is my first time setting up Spark i'm not sure how to troubleshoot it from here

Thank you

[Attempting to execute pyspark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le538.png)

[.profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv0gB.png)

[versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH982.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/bin/env: python2: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390206/usr-bin-env-python2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I read that thread and while similar I don't think it solves my issue. It details setting up the python path to solve the problem, I've already done this to no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who may come across this, I figured it out!

I specifically chose to use an older version of Spark in order to follow along with a tutorial I was watching - *Spark 2.1.0*. I did not know that the latest version of Python (3.5.6 at the time of writing this) is incompatible with Spark 2.1. Thus PySpark would not launch.

I solved this by using *Python 2.7* and setting the path accordingly in .bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPAH:/usr/lib/python2.7
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2.7
```

Comment: There is a typo in the first command, it should be like 
    `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7'

Answer (score 17):

You should have set `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` instead of export `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6.5` in your .profile

then `source .profile` , of course.

That's worked for me.

other options, installing `sudo apt python` (which is for 2.x ) is not appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

People using python 3.8 and Spark <= 2.4.5 will have the same problem.

In this case, the only solution I found is to update spark to V 3.0.0.

Look at https://bugs.python.org/issue38775

Answer (score 1):

for GNU/Linux users that have python3 package installed (ubuntu/debian distro's specially) you can find a package called "python-is-python3" this would help identifying python3 as python command.

```
# apt install python-is-python3
```

python 2.7 is deprecated now (2020 ubuntu 20.10) so do not try installing it.

Answer (score -5):

I have already solved this issue. Just type this command:

```
sudo apt install python
```